# How to merge a part of a data set using Stata?

Tags: merge, stata

I need to merge two data sets (`data1.dta` && `data2.dta`): `merge 1:1 personid using data2`

However I do not want to include all variables of `data2`. Is there any way to specify a list of variables of    `data2` that i want to include in `merge`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keep`:

```
// saving `data2` under a different name

...

save temporary
keep personid var1 var2 //list here all variables that you want to keep
merge 1:1 personid using temporary
erase temporary

// done!
```

Or simply this way:

```
// var1 var2 etc. are the variables that you want to keep
merge 1:1 personid using temporary, keepusing(var1 var2)
```

Comment: Quite. Before `merge` you can `keep` the variables you want or `drop` those you do not want. Not important which you use.

Comment: I might be complaining for nothing here, but honestly, the answer is written in plain, understandable text in the Stata documentation for `merge` (a truly versatile command, by the way).